# При открытии приложения настройки не применяются

Tags: android

В приложении делаю настройки, где по умолчанию указана основная валюта. Но при запуске приложения в первый раз приложение не видит выставленную основную валюту. А если перейти в настройки, то приложение начинает понимать, что выставлена основная валюта. Как это можно исправить?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Основная валюта">

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="RUB"
            android:entries="@array/currency_names"
            android:entryValues="@array/currency_codes"
            android:key="main_currency"
            android:summary="Выберите основную валюту"
            android:title="Основная валюта" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: По идее вам надо [что-то такое](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877795/3212712) при старте приложения вызвать: `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы применить настройки по умолчанию из файла настроек надо выполнить вот этот [код](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2877795/3212712) при старте приложения:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preference, false);
```